# IntelliJ IDEA: installing dependencies without build tools?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

How can you set up dependencies (the jar files that we usually grab from maven repository) in intellij, without using a build automation tool? Do u download them and install them in you're desktop and somehow connect them to the project you're working on in intellij or you're IDE of choice?

Comment: Why would you like to do that?

Comment: Add the jars to the module dependencies: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency. IntelliJ IDEA can download and set up dependencies from Maven even in the non-Maven project. They will be stored locally in the directory that you specify. Related help sections: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-project-library
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#download-libraries-from-maven. Does it help?

Comment: The reason why is important. Is this due to company policy? Or a restricted environment?

Comment: @CrazyCoder yes i think that's what i'm looking for. thanks, also it was mainly out of curiosity since i'm learning this stuff.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen 
  it was out of curiosity since i'm learning, but i already got an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA [has a feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-a-project-library) that allows to add a library from Maven into the project that is not using Maven. It will download the jars for you. You can also download the files manually and add them to the module dependencies from the disk.

[image: add library from Maven]